# Django, Mail not sending. Sendgrid

Tags: django, sendgrid

I am tring to send mail to the admin from contact form from the website via send grid. The Email is not getting delivered for some reason

Here is the **view.py**

```
def contact(request):
title = 'Contact'
form = contactForm(request.POST or None)
confirm_message = None

if form.is_valid():
    sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(apikey=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
    subject = 'Message from **'
    content = '%s %s' %(comment, name)
    from_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
    to_email = Email("***")
    try:
        mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    except:
        title="Sorry!"
        confirm_message = "Error sending message, Please try after sometime. Thank you!"
    title="Thanks"
    confirm_message = "Thanks for the message, We will get right back to you."
    form = None

context = {'title': title, 'form':form, 'confirm_message': confirm_message,}
template = "contact.html"
return render(request,template,context)
```

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '**'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
```

The email is set up in zoho.. and i am not able to get receive any emails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have sendgrid-django installed. Then in your settings it does not look like you have the sendgrid API Key. Try to add the following below:

SENDGRID_API_KEY = "Your SendGrid API Key"

See if this works.